# Define a type which have to allow key of an object inside an array from a generic type

Tags: typescript, generic-type-parameters

I'm trying to define a generic type for a component and I want to allow only the keys of an object for the **name** property of MySubInterface.

The issue I'm facing is that the type the interface receive is an array of Objects.
I've tried to use something like

```
name: Keys[number]
```

But the result is an error "Type 'number' cannot be used to index type 'Keys'".

The type is something like this

```ts
unique symbol | keyof { email: string; type: EmailType; isPrimary: boolean; }[]
```

and these are a sample of the interfaces

```ts
interface MyInterface<T, Key extends keyof T>{
    inputs: MySubInterface<T[Key], keyof T[Key]>[];
    name?: Key;
}
```

```ts
interface MySubInterface<T, Keys>{
    name: Keys
    component: (props: ComponentOptions<T>) => ReactNode
}
```

Some idea on how to get the list of keys in this case?
Thanks

Comment: I think your only problem is that you don't have any constraints on the `Keys` generic. If you change your `MySubInterface` to something like `MySubInterface<T, Keys extends (keyof T)[]>`, then using `Keys[number]` will work. Is that what you're trying to achive?

Comment: @Grochni yes, thanks, that is what i was trying to achive. Using ```MultiInputInput<T, Keys extends (keyof T)[]>``` and ```inputs: MultiInputInput<T[Key], T[Key]>[];``` the IDE will suggest me the right types for **name**. But it still report me an error on the second type here ```MultiInputInput<T[Key], T[Key]>[]``` Type 'T[Key]' does not satisfy the constraint '(keyof T[Key])[]'.